# Is there an Android equivalent of JavaFX's Timeline class?

Tags: android

I've just started messing around with the SDK, however, I can't find a similar Timeline class. I've seen some answers about JavaFXPorts but I'd like to just be able to move a circle back and forth with just a timer.

Answer (score 0):

There is some libraries maybe can helps you :

- https://github.com/sangcomz/StickyTimeLine
- https://github.com/vipulasri/Timeline-View
- https://github.com/vivian8725118/TimeLine